# Torrent over Sshuttle?

Tags: ssh, bittorrent

Running a torrent client like `Transimission`，having all network traffic over `sshuttle`, or `sudo sshuttle -r root@99.22.23.22 0/0 --dns -x 99.42.23.22 --python /usr/bin/python3`, is that the same behaviour likes VPN hiding my real IP address to another client while torrent file is active?

Comment: Is this question difficult or misunderstanding?

Comment: Is this question referring to Bittorrent downloading that is not allow to disscuss here？